# How can I sync specific Google contact groups?

Tags: contacts, htc-desire

My HTC Desire A8181 runs 2.2, and uses the People app to manage contacts instead of the vanilla Android contacts app. I'd like to use Google Contacts to manage my contacts and just sync with my phone, but People can't filter by group — so I end up with literally hundreds of extraneous contacts (making it a royal pain to create shortcuts, link contacts) and numerous duplicates (contacts with the same name but different email addresses cannot be distinguished).

HTC have confirmed that it is not possible to change this behaviour. So is there another application that I can use which will sync my contacts only with designated groups in Google Contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible options, though not ideal ones:

1. Flash a custom ROM that uses the vanilla Contacts app
2. Export your contacts from Google and import them manually (shut off sync)

Comment: Aaah... I didn't mention this because it seemed tangential, but #2 is not an option because HTC's People import/export modifies the numbers by adding dashes! Anyway, I'm contemplating #1, I'll wait to see if there are simpler approaches :)

Comment: @Mathew How does the vanilla Contacts app sync specific groups ? AFAIK it only syncs "My Contacts" group.

Comment: Eventually went with #1. HTC Sense just has too many cons.

Comment: @M.Sameer - it's under display options.